# How to make a form responsive as it looks good on some devices but not responsive on the others

Tags: css, mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" style="width:50%; top:15%;" role="dialog" >
      <div class="">
      
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-bodys" style="padding:20px 8px 20px 20px">
              <a style="background: #EAEAEA;" class="wt-closebtn close closeButtonJoinNOw" aria-label="Close"><i class="fa fa-times" data-dismiss="modal"></i></a>
            <form id="wt-single-joinnow-form" class="row">
              <h2 class="col-sm-12"> Join Us Now </h2>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6" >
                <label for="usrname"> First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter your first name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="usrname"> Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Enter your last name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-12" >
                <label for="usrname"> Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <label for="psw"> Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" minlength="8" maxlength="16"  id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                <span id="password_strength"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                <label for="psw"> Re-type Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" minlength="8" maxlength="16"  id="pass2" placeholder="Re-type your password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;">
                <span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
              </div>
    
                 <div class="formRadio123" id="customrediobtnmsgid">
                    <label>I want to start as:</label>&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div class="formRadio" id="customrediobtnid">
                    <input checked="checked" type="radio" class="" id="userTyp" name="user_type" value="freelancer">
                    <label for="Freelancer">Freelancer</label>&nbsp; 
                    <input   type="radio"  id="userType" name="user_type" value="Client">

                    <label for="Client">Client</label>&nbsp; 
                   <!--  <input style="visiblity:hidden !important; display: none;" type="radio" class="intersmodalclassclick" id="userType" name="user_type" value="Intern">
                     <label for="Intern">Intern</label> -->
                </div> 
              <div class="problemSignUpError" id="problemSignUpError"></div>
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="myBtn1" aria-hidden="true"> Join Now</button>
              
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});

</script>
```

I want to make this form responsive it is responsive for some sites but not responsive for the other so need to make it responsive . if anyone can guide me what to change in this code to make it responsive .I can share the css code for it as well as well as the form but I need to make it responsive on all mobiles devices . it works well on some but not on all .
[Not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGaKA.png) 
[Responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzf6H.png)

Comment: You can achieve this just by simple hack. Add `unique id or class` on main div and add that id or  class to all CSS properties. This is my personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use @media rule and different css for different device**

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  //your css
}
```

> You can change min and max-width according to ur device

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css property to specify the width to your form. as soon the width of device will go down from 570(which is most of the cell phones) it will change

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 570px) {
  /*
     write the width and height of your form by using form property or class containing 
     the form
  */
}
```